# Hash files serve static content web server

Tags: http, caching, static, cdn

I am writting my own static web content delivery routines. For caching I plan to include hashes in URLs like

/static/file.MD5HASH.png

I am developing in a static, compiled language. I read
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#cachedstaticfilesstorage
and
https://gist.github.com/3207357

Now my mental problem is how to determine efficiently the hash of a file? I will not calculate the hash upon every request to the server. So I need some caching.

I could write a helping program which takes the path to the static content, recursively calculates the hash and stores the result as

filename.png HASH

in a file called .cache.hash.lookup. This file is loaded on web server start and statet on every request so when a static file is about to be served it will look it up in the cache and if the cache is outdated, re-load the cache.

Is this feasible? Please I do not need advice how to do it using framework X as I would like to understand it and write my own routines.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your link, the idea there is to store multiple versions of the same resource, so adding the hash to the filename happens when you insert a new file.

Your HTTP server can be dumb and just look up files by name.
(another advantage I see is you can blindly respond with "304 Not changed" to any conditional request, as the hash in the filename acts as the etag.)

Or am I missing something?

Comment: Well, storing multiple versions of a file is a detail of cachedstaticfiles of Django.

My point is how can the webserver quickly add the hash of a requested file without recreating the hash upon every request. It has to maintain some sort of hash-cache which get's re-validated preferably by a background process which re-calculates a files hash as soon as the file changes.

Comment: Either I or you do not understand how this mechanism works: The hash is added to the filename at design time, so the HTML referencing the resource already has a URL like /static/file.MD5HASH.png The server does not need to know about the semantics of the weird filename at runtime. That is what is asked for, that is what is in the filesystem. Filesystem integrity validation is no concern of a webserver.